# Collection View does not update layout at Rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

This is the view of the app when it is in portrait mode. [image]

When it is rotated to landscape mode it looks like this

[image]

The view debugger shows that the `UIWindow` is not rotating as shown here [image]

The `UICollectionViewController` is created via StoryBoard. I've tried subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that implements `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange`, but it does not fix my issue.

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    CGRect oldBounds = self.collectionView.bounds;
    if (CGRectGetWidth(newBounds) != CGRectGetWidth(oldBounds)) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Please provide ideas of what to check next or requests for additional code to debug.

Edit - As suggested by MirekE, I attempted to add constraints to the `CollectionView` but was unable. All of the options for Editor->Pin are unavailable for the `CollectionView`.
[image]

Edit, response to Andrea -

I'm targeting iOS8.3. My understanding is that the main method called at rotation is `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`, which is from the `UIContentContainer` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html).  I've added the following to my CollectionViewController, but same problem persists

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
      withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: looks like you have given constraints specific to every cell, is that necessary ?

Comment: Vinay - yes there is a `topMargin` and `centerX` constraint on the label within the cell, but no constraints on the cell itself.

Comment: According to the doc, I think you should call the super implementation in `viewWillTransitionToSize` at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `collectionView` outlet was not properly set. After setting the `collectionView`, all works properly.

`collectionView` outlet not set:

[image]

`collectionView` outlet set:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I don't know which iOS version you ara targeting, but let me suppose that you know the rotation process and methods called in the view controller while it's happening.

In one of those methods you just need to call:

```
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
```

and maybe depending on your layout `-reloadData`
No need to subclass.

EDIT

I use this method, I guess that is not working because you should relayout the collection after it has resized:

```
- (void) willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super willTransitionToTraitCollection:newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];


    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];            
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }];

}
```

What I'm doing attach the layout invalidation process to the animation process.

Comment: I've updated the question with a response to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you have custom implementation of UICollectionViewLayout, try to override methods:

```
override public func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    let bounds = self.collectionView!.bounds;
    return ((CGRectGetWidth(newBounds) != CGRectGetWidth(bounds) ||
        (CGRectGetHeight(newBounds) != CGRectGetHeight(bounds))));
}

override public func invalidateLayout() {
    cache.removeAll()  // remove layout attributes ans settings if they exist
    super.invalidateLayout()

}
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just drag the collection view on the canvas, but did not add any constraints. So when you rotate the device, the size does not change.

In the storyboard select the collection view, then click on the Pin icon at the bottom of Xcode and add constraints for the top, left, bottom and right margins. After you do that, the collection view should resize on rotation.

Comment: The Collection View was added automatically when I dragged the Collection View Controller on to the Canvas. I've updated the question with a screenshot to show what happens when I try to pin the Collection View. No options are available to add constraints. Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: My suggestion would be for a collection view dragged to an existing controller. If this is CollectionViewController, you should not need to do anything. It fills the space correctly as I rotate the simulator in a little project I created to test it right now. Perhaps you added some custom code that overrides the defaults? Did you try to comment out your customizations?